# Create labels dynamicly on ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to create labels in my page `dynamicly`, for example the user will `choose` in a textbox the number of labels, and I will display the number of this label with .text = "XYZ".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty method (this example adds 10 labels and literals to a PlaceHolder on an ASP.NET page:

```
Dim c As Integer = 0
While c < 10
    Dim lab As New Label()
    Dim ltr As New Literal()
    lab.Text = c.ToString()
    ltr.Text = "<br/>"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lab)
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ltr)
    C+=1
End While
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057533/adding-link-to-a-label-asp-net-vb

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a Repeater control:

[Using the ASP.NET Repeater Control](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control)

[Data Repeater Controls in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things that will need to be done to make this work, but to simply dynamically create controls and add them to the page, you will need a `Placeholder` on your ASPX page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLabelCount" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create" /><br />
<asp:Placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

Then, in `btnCreate`'s click event handler:

```
' Number of labels to create. txtLabelCount should be validated to ensure only integers are passed into it
Dim labelCount As Integer = txtLabelCount.Text

For i As Integer = 0 To labelCount - 1
    ' Create the label control and set its text attribute
    Dim Label1 As New Label
    Label1.Text = "XYZ"

    Dim Literal1 As New Literal
    Literal1.Text = "<br />"

    ' Add the control to the placeholder
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Label1)
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Literal1)
Next
```

Comment: @AZIRAR - Sorry, forgot about that. Simply add a new literal with its text set to `<br />` after the label. I've modified my answer to show this. By the way, the XHTML way of doing `<br>` is `<br />`.