# Adding link to a label ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, hyperlink, label, onclick

I have a `label` and I want to add to it a link.

I want to use `javascript` like :

```
MyLabel.Attributes.Add("`onclick`", "javascript:`SOME_CODE`")
```

What must I add in (`SOME_CODE`) to redirect the user to another link.

Thanks.

Comment: Have the replies answered your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried: `window.location = 'http://google.com'` ?
Are the any particular reason you want to use Javascript for this, and not just the HyperLink Control?

**Update:**

You can either use a normal a-tag `<a href="http://google.com">link</a>` or use the ASP.Net HyperLink control:

This is the markup:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="MyHyperLinkControl" NavigateUrl="http://google.com" runat="server" />
```

This is if you want to add it from the code-behind:

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.NavigateUrl = "http://google.com";

parentControl.Controls.Add(link);
```

Where `parentControl`, is the container you want to add it to, for instance a cell in a table or a panel.

See [here](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/controls/panel.aspx) for more information on how to add a control to a panel

Comment: I think `window.location.href` is more reliable than `window.location` between different types of browsers.

Comment: @Paperjam, you are right window.location.href would be the more correct one because window.location is basically the object containing other properties, among them href. window.location can however be used as a shorthand for window.location.href.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a plain anchor tag (`<a >`), but put the label *inside* the anchor (the reverse is not strictly valid html).  If you don't want it to show up as a link every time, you can accomplish that by omitting the `href` attribute.  This is easy to do with a normal `<asp:HyperLink>` server control like so:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="..." runat="server"><asp:Label ... ></asp:Label></asp:HyperLink>
```

Now, the href attribute will only render if you actually set the NavigateUrl property in your code.  You might also find that using an `<asp:HyperLink>` completely replaces the need for the label.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://google.com" >Go to Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this has anything to do with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057299), use a `Hyperlink` control instead of a `Label`:

```
    Dim Hyperlink1 As New Hyperlink
    Hyperlink1.Text = "XYZ"
    Hyperlink1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com"

    Dim Literal1 As New Literal
    Literal1.Text = "<br />"

    ' Add the control to the placeholder
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Hyperlink1)
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Literal1)
```